# GoogleDoc ImportHtml (importing a wikipedia list)

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to import the following wikipedia list using the following command but its not working, am not sure what the correct index should be.

I would like to have the name in one column and the wikipedia url in another column if possible.

```
    =ImportHtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ice_Bucket_Challenge_participants","list", 2)
```

Also if possible, removing square brackets with the number beside each name

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImportHtml` is not sufficiently powerful / advanced for what you want to do.
Use [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) function instead. You will need understanding of [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp) to be able to write the queries you need.

Also keep in mind that google docs supports only a subset of the xpath functions available. This is similar to Xpath 1.0, but still some functions don't work. Don't ask me why....

I have had a go, and written what you need. For reasons I am not going to go into, to be able to give you the reference number, I had to create a separate list of names with and without references.

[image]

The formulas are:

- A4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a[following-sibling::sup]")
  ```
- B4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a[following-sibling::sup/a/text()]/@href")
  ```
- C4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a[following-sibling::sup/a/text()]/@href")
  ```
- E4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a[not(following-sibling::sup)]")
  ```
- F4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a[not(following-sibling::sup)]/@href")
  ```

**EDIT:**

If you are not bothered about the reference then you can have all the names in one list.

I've also added an additional query for the image link

New formulas:

- A4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a")
  ```
- B4:

  ```
  =importxml(A1,"//div[@class='div-col columns column-width']//li/a/@href")
  ```
- C4:

  ```
  ="http://en.wikipedia.org"&importxml("http://en.wikipedia.org"&B4,"//table[@class='infobox biography vcard' or @class='infobox vcard']//td[@colspan='2']//a[@class='image']/@href")
  ```

Comment: this worked perfect, I did not need the reference number. would it be possible for you to tweak what you did to give me the img url for each of the names that shows up on the top right for each person? I would really appreciate it, thank you so much for the formulas, they are exactly what i wanted